# Order of execution of targets in NAnt

Tags: target, nant, depends

From the NAnt help page (http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/fundamentals/targets.html):

> NAnt tries to execute the targets in the depends attribute in the
>   order they appear from left to right.  It is possible that a target
>   can get executed earlier when an earlier target depends on it:
>
> ```
> <target name="A"/>
> <target name="B" depends="A" />
> <target name="C" depends="B" />
> <target name="D" depends="C,B,A" /
> ```
>
> Suppose we want to execute target D.  From its depends attribute, you might think that first target C, then B and then A is
>   executed.  Wrong!  C depends on B, and B depends on A, so first A is
>   executed, then B, then C, and finally D.

Since C depends on B and B depends on A, shouldn't the depends attribute of target (D) should be C only?

If I would replace depends of D with "C" alone, what would be the order of execution? Would it alter from the previous order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the targets as specified in the example:

```
<target name="A" />
<target name="B" depends="A" />
<target name="C" depends="B" />
<target name="D" depends="C,B,A" />
```

If you execute `D`, the order of execution will be `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`.  This is due to the dependency chains - a target that is depended on must execute before the target that depends on it.  If you replaced the `depends` attribute of `D` with just `C`, you're right - the execution order would still be the same.

What this example is highlighting however, is that the dependencies *may not* be executed in the same order as specified in the `depends` attribute.  For example, if you just had these targets:

```
<target name="A" />
<target name="B" />
<target name="C" />
<target name="D" depends="C,B,A" />
```

and executed `D`, the order of execution would now match the order of the `depends` attribute - ie `C`, `B`, `A`, `D`.